# Rails command not available after installing with gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler, gemfile

I installed rails via a Gemfile and `bundle install`:

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rails",  "5.0.6"
```

the gem appears to have successfully installed according to success message. However it is still not available from the command line even after a restart.

```
$ rails
The program 'rails' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby-railties
You will have to enable the component called 'universe'
```

I am using rbenv (required) and have a number of utilities in `/.rbenv/shims/` (gem, rake, bundle, etc.) but not rails... so I don't know where it got installed.

`gem env` returns:

```
GEM PATHS:
 - /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
 - /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
```

but I don't see those packages there. I'm guessing it needs to be on the path, but I don't know where it is. The solution needs to work while installing with a bash script.

Comment: have you tried `gem install rails`?

Comment: Check if you installed in the same ruby version you are currently using. For each ruby version it has a different repository of gems. Type gem list to display all the gems installed in current ruby version. If it is there, so you will need to make sure the $PATH is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was running `rbenv rehash` and setting the environment variable. However, the new env variables were not available until after a restart. Using the full path to `/.rbenv/shims/rake` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

just add `bundle exec`

```
bundle exec rails
```

Comment: Hi, this is not good way to do, even if it does works, as it meant to work with environment specified in the Gemfile. The right way is what @spickermann wrote !

Comment: This is still a good suggestion. The OP installed using a Gemfile & bundler, the correct way to run a command installed this way is to prepend `bundle exec` (as noted in this answer) unless you explicitly know your shell is set up to prepend/prefix `bundle exec` for you. The OP should have installed via `gem install rails` if he wanted it available without `bundle exec`

Answer (score 1):

When you use rbenv and you install Ruby on Rails then you might need to run [`rbenv rehash`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash) to make the `rails` command available.

From the docs:

> Installs shims for all Ruby executables known to rbenv (i.e., `~/.rbenv/versions/*/bin/*`). Run this command after you install a new version of Ruby, or install a gem that provides commands.

Answer (score 0):

after I read your problem, I guess that you used `rbenv` and you didn't run `rbenv rehash`, so you can do it as following below:

```
gem install railties 
rbenv rehash
```